# Center updated image PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have an image in PySimpleGUI that I want always to be centered. This image must change as the user input different data.

I include the image in a layout:

`layout = [[sg.Image(filename="default.png", key='image', size=(680, 360))]]`

To ensure that the image is centered, I place it within a Column:

`sg.Column(layout, size=(650, 400), justification='center')`

With that, the first image (*default.png*) is centered.

The problem comes when I update the image when the user input data. I use

`window['image'].update(new_image.png)`

but this automatically aligns the image to the left instead of remaining centered as I expected.

Is there any other option to update an image and this one still be centered?
Or what should I do to maintain the image centered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't recommend hard coding sizes on anything in PySimpleGUI if I can avoid it.  Placing a `sg.Push()` element on each side of your Image element will center it.

Comment: The size of Image element will be changed as you updated the image, try to call `window['Image'].update(filename=path, size=(680, 360))`.

Comment: The problem was not the size but the alignment. Applying `sg.Push()` solved the problem, and I will take that into consideration to keep the elements centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center one or more elements on a row, place a `Push` element on each side.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Text('My Window with an Image centered')],
            [sg.Push(), sg.Image(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_WIZARD, key='-IMAGE-'), sg.Push()],
            [sg.Button('Change'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Image Centered', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Change':
        window['-IMAGE-'].update(sg.PYTHON_COLORED_HEARTS_BASE64)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: There are numerous of ways of making this happen.  This is the simplest way I can think of currently that uses the least amount of code and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the Push and VPush helper functions.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

default_path = "D:/default.png"

layout = [
    [sg.Input(default_path, disabled=True, enable_events=True, expand_x=True, key='Path'),
     sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("All PNG Files", "*.png"),))],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Image(filename=default_path, key='Image'), sg.Push()],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Text(expand_x=True, key='Status')],
]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)
window.maximize()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Path":
        path = values[event]
        try:
            window['Image'].update(filename=path)
        except Exception as e:
            window['Status'].update(e)
            continue
        window['Status'].update("Image file loaded !")

window.close()
```

Another way is to use th option `expand_x` and `expand_y`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

default_path = "D:/default.png"

layout = [
    [sg.Input(default_path, disabled=True, enable_events=True, expand_x=True, key='Path'),
     sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("All PNG Files", "*.png"),))],
    [sg.Image(filename=default_path, expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='Image')],
    [sg.Text(expand_x=True, key='Status')],
]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)
window.maximize()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Path":
        path = values[event]
        try:
            window['Image'].update(filename=path)
        except Exception as e:
            window['Status'].update(e)
            continue
        window['Status'].update("Image file loaded !")

window.close()
```

Note: It maybe not work well if you have other elements on the same row with different value for option `expand_x`.